# How can I calculate $\int_{|y|\ge a} \frac{1}{|y|^4} dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How can I calculate $n$-dimensional ($y\in \mathbb R^n$) integral of

$$
\int_{|y|\ge a} \frac{1}{|y|^4} dy
$$
where $a>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_n$ denote the surface area of a unit $n$-sphere. Then
$$\int_{\vert y\vert > a}\frac{1}{\vert y\vert^4}\, dV = \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{r^4} \cdot \lambda_{n-1}r^{n-1}\, dr = \lambda_{n-1}\int_a^\infty r^{n-5}\,dr$$
The first equality can be thought of as dividing the volume of integration into $n-1$-spherical shells, noting that their contribution to the integral is th surface area of the sphere times $\frac{1}{\vert y \vert}$, and integrating. For $n<4$, this integral can be evaluated directly. Otherwise, the integral doesn't converge.